# handling sleep in java scheduled executor service

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a sort of complex problem like below.
- we have a real time system with large number threads requirement. In order to optimize the performance, we are thinking of following design.

- create a thread pool executor with max number of threads
- each thread is used to create scheduled executor service.
- now the tasks are being assigned to these executor services evenly based on load
- BUT the biggest problem is, if one of the task in the queue contains a sleep (for few secs), it blocks the corresponding Schedule executor service thread for that duration and subsequently all the following tasks in that queue.
- In this regard, please suggest me how to suspend the execution of the task with sleep OR overriding the sleep somehow and rejoin/schedule the task again to the queue.

Thanks in advance
Seshu

Comment: executors generally execute smaller tasks. does your smaller task need to sleep for several seconds. that sounds like there could be some design issues there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question, your Schedule Executor service threads have a deadline requirement, but the actual workers can sleep for an unknown length of time, possibly throwing off the timing of the Schedule Executors.  From your description I'm guessing what you want is for a task that needs to sleep to actually stop, save progress information and then requeue itself for the remainder of the work to be rescheduled at some future time.  You'd have to build this into your application architecture.

Alternatively, you could have the scheduler threads launch the worker tasks in their own separate threads, letting them sleep as necessary, with one scheduler thread collecting all the worker terminations.

To get a better answer you're going to have to provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Tasks which sleep are inherently unfriendly for running in any kind of bounded thread pool. The sleep is explicitly telling the thread that it must do nothing for a period of time.

If possible, split the task into 2 (or more parts), eliminating the sleep completely. Get the first half-task to schedule the second task with an appropriate delay.

Failing that, you could consider increasing the size of your thread pool somewhat - either setting a much larger cap to its size, or possibly even eliminating the cap altogether (not recommended for a server than might end up with many clients).

Alternatively, move the tasks with sleep statements in them into their own Scheduled executor. Then, they'll delay each other, but better-behaved tasks, with no wait statements in them, will get preferential treatment.